# Where put mariadb jcontroller .jar in linux?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, mariadb

I have to use my db on Mariadb (installed thank to Xampp) with a Java program.
This is the code i wrote :

```
 String host =  "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/prova" ;
 String user ="root";
 String password =***;
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,password);
```

But out the error :`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/prova`

so where i have to put this driver?
(Distro : Deepin Linux  deb based)

Comment: You can put it in any directories found on the `classpath`.

Comment: How could i control the classpath directories ?

Comment: If you run your program by `java` command, you can add `-cp` option: `java -cp /path/to/mariadb-java-client-X.X.X.jar your.package.YourMainClass`